# windows laptop event log power source change from battery to ac power

Tags: laptop, power-supply, battery, power

For the windows laptop event log power source change, how can I tell if it is switching from AC power to battery or from battery to AC power?

I attach a screenshot here.

[image: Windows Event Log switching from battery to AC power]

It seems impossible to tell from the Windows Event Log.

Internet search does not provide any answers.

Comment: Does [GitHub - hirschmann/powereventprovider: Power Event Provider service for Windows](https://github.com/hirschmann/powereventprovider) answer your question?

Comment: I think you need to take a closer look at your event log. There are events which say if it is on AC or battery.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to DavidPostill who suggested :
https://github.com/hirschmann/powereventprovider ;
[GitHub - hirschmann/powereventprovider: Power Event Provider service for Windows]

It looks quite promising, claiming to do what I wanted. I was unsure if the software was safe but the author looks reputable. I installed the .exe file easily in less than a minute.

I then created a Custom View under Applications and Services Logs in Windows Event Viewer according to the user guide on the webpage, choosing Event source as PowerEventProvider.

I switched off the electrical supply from the mains AC power then a minute later switched from battery to main AC power.

The events are successfully recorded in detail as I show in my screenshot below.

[image: system power source changed - battery or AcPowerSource]

Thanks to Appleoddity for commenting but my Windows Event Viewer (under Windows Logs -> System) makes no distinction between AC or battery, simply logging it as "Power source changed." It is necessary to install the software suggested by DavidPostill.